# DataTables.net dataTable.columns(0).search('term').draw() does not populate columns[0][search][value]

Tags: jquery, yii, datatables

I have been banging my head since 2 days on an issue which appears to be very simple and has plenty of help available but I can't get it to work. I m trying to do a server side search on each column of the grid and when I call `dataTable.columns(0).search('search-term').draw()` the POST request it generates always has the `columns[0][search][value]` empty.

Below are the two approaches I tried over and over trying different things and neither of these work for me, clearly there is something I am missing.

[I also attached a snapshot for clarity](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jyuxb.png), also, below is the full configuration of my DataTable, can anybody please point me what am I doing wrong.

**Approach #1**

```
initComplete: function () {

        $('.scheduling-search')
            .on('keyup change', function () {
                var i = $(this).attr('data-column');
                var v = $(this).val();
                schedulingGrid.columns(i).search(v).draw();
            }
        );
    }
```

**Approach #2**

```
schedulingGrid.columns().every( function () {
    var column = this;
    $( 'input', this.footer() ).on( 'keyup change', function () {
        column
            .search( this.value )
            .draw();
    } );
});
```

**Here is the full configuration of my DataTable**

```
var schedulingGrid = $('#scheduling-manager-grid').DataTable({
    processing: true,
    searchDelay: 1000,
    pageLength: {$pageSize},
    paginate: true,
    lengthChange: false,
    filter: false,
    info: true,
    autoWidth: false,
    serverSide: true,
    order: [[3, '{$defaultSortOrder}']],
    language: {
        paginate: {
            next: '',
            previous: ''
        }
    },
    ajax: {
        type: 'post',
        url: '{$url}',
    },
    columns: [
        {
            width: '40px',
            data: 'briefingId',
            name: 'id',
            searchable: true,
            orderable: true
        },
        {
            width: '100px',
            data: 'briefingTitle',
            name: 't.title',
            searchable: true,
            orderable: true
        },
        {
            width: '100px',
            data: 'dateSubmitted',
            name: 't.created_at',
            searchable: true,
            orderable: true
        },
        {
            width: '100px',
            data: 'preferredDate',
            name: 't.preferred_date',
            searchable: true,
            orderable: true
        },
        {
            width: '100px',
            data: 'requesterName',
            name: 't.requestor_name',
            searchable: true,
            orderable: true
        },
        {
            width: '100px',
            data: 'briefingStatus',
            name: 't.briefing_status_id',
            searchable: true,
            orderable: true
        },
        {
            width: '100px',
            data: 'briefingType',
            name: 't.briefing_type_id',
            searchable: true,
            orderable: true
        },
        {
            data: 'notes',
            name: 'notes',
            searchable: true,
            orderable: false
        }
    ],
    initComplete: function () {

        $('.scheduling-search')
            .on('keyup change', function () {
                var i = $(this).attr('data-column');
                var v = $(this).val();
                schedulingGrid.columns(i).search(v).draw();
            }
        );
    }
});
```

**And the HTML goes like**

```
<table id="scheduling-manager-grid">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Briefing ID</th>
      <th>Briefing Title</th>
      <th>Date Submitted</th>
      <th>Preferred Briefing Date</th>
      <th>Requestor Name</th>
      <th>Briefing Status</th>
      <th>Briefing Type</th>
      <th>Notes</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <td><input style="width: 50px;" type="text" data-column="0" class="scheduling-search"></td>
      <td><input style="width: 80px;" type="text" data-column="1" class="scheduling-search"></td>
      <td><input style="width: 80px;" type="text" data-column="2" class="scheduling-search"></td>
      <td><input style="width: 80px;" type="text" data-column="3" class="scheduling-search"></td>
      <td><input style="width: 80px;" type="text" data-column="4" class="scheduling-search"></td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
  </thead>
</table>
```

Comment: There are the answers I have been following along with many other...

# https://coderexample.com/datatable-custom-column-search/
# https://datatables.net/forums/discussion/22431/per-column-searching-not-working
# https://datatables.net/forums/discussion/31978/why-is-the-column-search-not-working-after-i-implemented-german-json-file

Answer (score 0):

**SOLUTION**

I configured datatable wrong. Allan from datatables.net pointed out the issue and it fixed it. I had to remove `filter: false` from the configuration to make it work.

See complete discussion here: https://datatables.net/forums/discussion/comment/98607#Comment_98607